# Develop a protocol that allows the user to send a calendar date (mm/dd). What is the minimum number of bits necessary

Tags: binary, bit

What is the minimum number of bits necessary to do this? I am trying to answer a homework question and I think the answer is 8, but my classmate is telling me it's 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classmate is right. Each calendar date has to have a unique representation. 8 bits will give you 2<sup>8</sup> = 256 unique representations, but you need 366 (potential leap day). 2<sup>9</sup> = 512, which is more than enough. You can calculate the number of bits required by taking the ceiling of log base 2 of 366.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. As a follow up, do I apply the same logic if I want to find the minimum number of bits to send a time in military format HHMMSS?

Comment: Yup, you're going to want the number of unique times, so the number of seconds in a day. Take the log base 2 of that!